# R terra SpatVectorCollection: How to convert SpatVectorCollection to SpatVector (multiple polygons)

Tags: r, polygon, raster, r-sf, terra

In general, is it possible to convert a terra SpatVectorCollection to a multi-polygon SpatVector so that it can be plotted etc?
Specifically, I have a data.frame of extents (bounding boxes) that I need to convert to a set of polygons.
I can create a terra SpatVectorCollection but can't get any further.
Or, should I be doing this in sf not terra?

```
    library(terra)

    library(sf)

    exts <- data.frame(xmin = c(-82,80), xmax = c(-80,-78), ymin = c(-2,-2), ymax = c(0,0))

    exts.svc <- apply(exts, 1, ext) %>% lapply(as.polygons) %>% svc()

    merge(exts.svc) # doesn't work

    union(exts.svc) # doesn't work

    vect(exts.svc) # doesn't work
```

Comment: If you `str(exts.svc)` result, you'll note your attr(s) are likely not what you expect.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `vect` to combine a list of SpatVectors into a single SpatVector. So you do not need to make a SpatVectorCollection

```
library(terra)
exts <- data.frame(xmin = c(-82,-80), xmax = c(-80,-78), ymin = c(-2,-2), ymax = c(0,0))
e <- apply(exts, 1, ext)
lapply(e, as.polygons) |> vect()

# class       : SpatVector 
# geometry    : polygons 
# dimensions  : 2, 0  (geometries, attributes)
# extent      : -82, -78, -2, 0  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. :
```

If you have a SpatVectorCollection with SpatVectors of the same geometry

```
s <- lapply(e, as.polygons) |> svc()
```

You can combine now those into a single SpatVector like this

```
vect(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can avoid the call to `svc()` it is a little easier to get to `sf` polygons.  If not, the beginnings of a method to get polygons from the `SpatVectorCollection` is included below as well.

```r
library(terra)
library(sf)
library(tidyverse) #just dplyr should work too

exts <- data.frame(xmin = c(-82,80), xmax = c(-80,-78), ymin = c(-2,-2), ymax = c(0,0))

# This gives a spatrastercollection, but is more difficult to work with
exts.svc <- apply(exts, 1, ext) %>% lapply(as.polygons) %>% svc()

# Avoiding spatrastercollection using exts directly
# create extent, make polygons, make sf, bind, and set crs to 4326
exts_sf <- apply(exts, 1, ext) %>% 
  lapply(as.polygons) %>%
  lapply(st_as_sf) %>%
  bind_rows() %>%
  st_set_crs(4326)

head(exts_sf)
#> Simple feature collection with 2 features and 0 fields
#> Geometry type: POLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -82 ymin: -2 xmax: 80 ymax: 0
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#>                         geometry
#> 1 POLYGON ((-82 -2, -82 0, -8...
#> 2 POLYGON ((80 -2, 80 0, -78 ...
```

Above returns an `sf` object of `POLYGON` type, use `st_union` on `exts_sf` if you need `MULTIPOLYGON`.
[image]

```
# Working with exts.svc
# two slots
length(exts.svc)
#> [1] 2

# transforming the first polygon/slot to an sf polygon
exts.svc[1] %>% st_as_sf() %>% st_set_crs(4326)
#> Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 0 fields
#> Geometry type: POLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -82 ymin: -2 xmax: -80 ymax: 0
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#>                         geometry
#> 1 POLYGON ((-82 -2, -82 0, -8...
```

Maybe a loop, *apply, or map* function would work to programmatically get each slot of `exts.svc` to return an `sf` polygon object if you're stuck with an object like `exts.svc`.

<sup>Created on 2022-03-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Taking your data:

```
exts <- data.frame(xmin = c(-82,80), xmax = c(-80,-78), ymin = c(-2,-2), ymax = c(0,0))

#as expected
exts
  xmin xmax ymin ymax
1  -82  -80   -2    0
2   80  -78   -2    0
# then your apply
> exts.ext <- apply(exts, 1, ext) 
> exts.ext
[[1]]
SpatExtent : -82, -80, -2, 0 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)

[[2]]
SpatExtent : 80, -78, -2, 0 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)

# then you lapply using just as.polygons
> exts.polys <- lapply(exts.ext, as.polygons)
exts.polys
[[1]]
 class       : SpatVector 
 geometry    : polygons 
 dimensions  : 1, 0  (geometries, attributes)
 extent      : -82, -80, -2, 0  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
 coord. ref. :  

[[2]]
 class       : SpatVector 
 geometry    : polygons 
 dimensions  : 1, 0  (geometries, attributes)
 extent      : -78, 80, -2, 0  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
 coord. ref. : 
#then, I suppose svc()
exts.svc <- lapply(exts.polys, svc)
> exts.svc
[[1]]
 class       : SpatVectorCollection 
 length      : 1 
 geometry    : polygons (1)

[[2]]
 class       : SpatVectorCollection 
 length      : 1 
 geometry    : polygons (1)
```

And then do whatever other operations. When working out (even simple) workflows, I generally do this step by step before introducing `%>%` or `|>` so I can check the results of intermediate steps and that they are progressing as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same challenge and I wanted a solution without using {sf}.

See below for the reprex - if the SpatialVectorCollection is required convert to a list and then use rbind in `do.call`. or just skip the svc step altogether if it's not required.

```r
library(terra)
#> terra 1.7.3

exts <- data.frame(xmin = c(-82,-80), xmax = c(-80,-78), ymin = c(-2,-2), ymax = c(0,0))

exts.svc <- apply(exts, 1, ext)  |>  lapply(as.polygons) |> svc()

exts.poly <- lapply(1:length(exts.svc), function(x) exts.svc[x]) 
exts.poly <- do.call(rbind, exts.poly)

# if the svc is not required just do: 

exts.list <- apply(exts, 1, ext)  |>  lapply(as.polygons)
exts.poly <- do.call(rbind, exts.list)
plot(exts.poly)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>